# Elastic Search ignores `token_chars`

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer, n-gram

I'm using Elastic Search 1.7.1 on Mac.

Here is my index mapping:

```
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "my_edgengram":{
               "max_gram":15,
               "token_chars":[
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ],
               "type":"edgeNGram",
               "min_gram":1
            },
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "stop_edgengram_analyzer":{
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "stop",
                  "my_edgengram"
               ],
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"whitespace"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Debugging analyzer:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/objects/_analyze?analyzer=stop_edgengram_analyzer&text=America,s&pretty=True'
{
  "tokens" : [
     ... skipped ...
  , {
    "token" : "america",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "america,",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "america,s",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Why `america,s` token is in output?

`,` is punctuation symbol. I expect letters and digits only as specified in token_chars property of `my_edgengram` filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) and [edge_ngram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html).

From documentation:

> Tokenizers are used to break a string down into a stream of terms or
>   tokens.

In the example provided in question `whitespace` is the tokenizer that is being used

Token Filter on other hand :

> accept a stream of tokens from a tokenizer and can
>   modify tokens (eg lowercasing), delete tokens (eg remove stopwords) or
>   add tokens (eg synonyms).

In the example provided in OP `egde_ngram` token filter is being used.

`token_chars` is not supported for `edge_ngram` token filter and hence ignored.